# Where can I find oracle XE 10g packages

Tags: oracle

I am trying to download Oracle Xpress Edition 10g but cant't find the packages. 
I need it because I have a 32 bits machine But it seems like they have been removed from Oracle website.
Can you guys tell me where can I find the deb packages of Oracle XE 10g . 
Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [download](https://oss.oracle.com/debian/dists/unstable/non-free/binary-i386/) on the Debian unstable still holds them. Grab a copy and assume it will be deleted tomorrow so keep it safe somewhere.